# Difference Between Python two Class definitions

Tags: python, class, variables, constructor, instance

I'm new to programming and I want to know what is the difference between these two class definitions? Which one is a better and safer definition?
the one with instance variables or the one with constructor method?

Thanks

```
class MyClass1:

    def doAdd (self,val1=0,val2=0):

        sum1=val1+val2

        print("MyClass1")

        print ("{0}+{1}={2}".format(val1,val2,sum1))

class MyClass2: 

    def __init__(self,val1=0,val2=0):

        self.val1=val1

        self.val2=val2

    def doAdd(self):

        sum2=self.val1+self.val2

        print("MyClass2")

        print("{0}+{1}={2}".format(self.val1,self.val2,sum2)) 

obj1=MyClass1()

obj1.doAdd(1,2)

obj2=MyClass2(1,2)

obj2.doAdd()
```

---

```
MyClass1

1+2=3

MyClass2

1+2=3
```

Comment: I'd suggest that if you want to keep `val1` and `val2` for use in other methods and parts of the class, then use `Class2`. If you don't need to keep the values, then there's no point in keeping them; use `Class1` in this case.

Comment: @Khalil Ammour - There is no need to put extra line space in code, and "Thanks" to question. This will add noise to question. Keep in while Suggest Edit on Question.

Answer (score 1):

#### MyClass1

You may want to do the addition and store the sum in the `__init__()` method to avoid having it recalculated every time `doAdd()` is called. And like @gragas says, this method lets you store the data for later use in other methods.

#### MyClass2

You're not using any object oriented features here, so it might as well just be a regular function.

```
def doAdd(val1=0, val2=0):
    return val1 + val2

print(doAdd(1, 2))
```